# sql server 2012, Link server Save data

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I'm Making an application, i have 1 table in 1 device using Mysql, and i already connect to another device Using SQL SERVER with ODBC,  That table from Mysql is doing update every 2-3 seconds, i wanna save that data on SQL SERVER, how can i do that? first the table from mysql need to duplicate on a  new table create on SQL SERVER, after that they both change data at the same time (i hope) i would like to make like a "historian report".

Comment: Select the data from mysql into a staging table in sql server, then compare and insert/update..